# How to use tensorflow.feature_column outside of Estimator for prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want to use the tensorflow feature_column and feature directly with a session, bypassing the Estimator framework. I read [tensorflow's low level introduction on feature column](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/low_level_intro#feature_columns). The problem is that `tf.feature_column.input_layer` needs the `features` feed at construction, but the feature feeds are different between training and prediction time. Looking at the `tf.Estimator` codes, it seems the way is to call the same construction callback function again to get the graph. I came up with the example below, but it fails on table not initialized if I skip the table init after the second construction; or it would complain table already initialized if I do run the table init. According to [their research paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjUjJ_eyvnZAhVSxmMKHRN6AG4QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fterrytangyuan.github.io%2Fdata%2Fpapers%2Ftf-estimators-kdd-paper.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1GRD2TDraG09Eu6wCqHNC7), this is by design since they always expect a new model to be reloaded from save point. But this will be very inefficient for situation like reinforcement learning where we want to do updates and inferences at the same time in a training loop. It is also unclear how they want to do dev validation.

What's the correct way to construct graph and feed features for prediction?

```
training_features = {
    'sales' : [[5], [10], [8], [9]],
    'department': ['sports', 'sports', 'gardening', 'gardening']}

test_features = {
    'sales' : [[10], [20], [16], [18]],
    'department': ['sports', 'sports', 'gardening', 'gardening']}

department_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        'department', ['sports', 'gardening'])
department_column = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(department_column)

columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('sales'),
    department_column
]

# similar to a tf.Estimator's model_fn callback
def mkgraph(features):
    with tf.variable_scope('feature_test', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        inputs = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, columns)
        alpha = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='alpha')
        output = inputs * alpha
        return output, alpha

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    output, alpha = mkgraph(training_features)
    print('output', output)
    print('alpha', alpha)
    var_init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    table_init = tf.tables_initializer()
    with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
        sess.run([var_init, table_init])
        print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={alpha: 100.0})) # works here

        print('testing')
        output, alpha = mkgraph(test_features)
        print('output', output)
        print('alpha', alpha)
        table_init = tf.tables_initializer()
        # sess.run([table_init]) # with this, it fails on 'table already initialized'
        # without table_init run, it fails on 'table not initialized'
        print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={alpha: 200.0}))
```

Comment: Hi, I've come across a similar dilemma with `feature_column`. Have you got this problem solved? Will adding a switch to toggle between training and testing help?

Comment: For the dev validation part, I think the training loop already does the cross validation and so we don't need to do outside. But there is no answer for the general problem of iterative feeding training data and inference data in RL kind situation

Comment: I think I had a simpler case than you do with RL. But in general, I need to switch between a train set and a test set, using `feature_column`. Adding a switch helped me, though I'm not sure if that's the best way to go. Hopefully my answer below can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one training dataset and one testing dataset and you need to switch between them back and forth, you may try using a `is_training` switch. For your specific example in the question:

```
import tensorflow as tf

training_features = {
    'sales' : [[5], [10], [8], [9]],
    'department': ['sports', 'sports', 'gardening', 'gardening']}
test_features = {
    'sales' : [[10], [20], [16], [18]],
    'department': ['sports', 'sports', 'gardening', 'gardening']}

department_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        'department', ['sports', 'gardening'])
department_column = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(department_column)
columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('sales'),
    department_column
]

with tf.variable_scope('feature_test', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    alpha = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='alpha')
    is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='is_training')
    training_inputs = tf.feature_column.input_layer(training_features, columns)
    test_inputs = tf.feature_column.input_layer(test_features, columns)
    output = tf.cond(is_training,
                     lambda: training_inputs * alpha,
                     lambda: test_inputs * alpha)

var_init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
table_init = tf.tables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([var_init, table_init])

    print('training')
    print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={alpha: 100.0, is_training: True}))

    print('testing')
    print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={alpha: 200.0, is_training: False}))
```

One potential problem is that both `feature_column`s are initiated. I don't think they will just load everything and eat up memory. But they may cost more memory than necessary and potentially give you some troubles.